# Canonical way to display Google Guava table in JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, guava

Is there a canonical way to display a Google Guava table in a JavaFX TableView? I'm hoping for something like

```
com.google.common.collect.Table guavaTable = ...;
javafx.scene.control.TableView<Object> tableView = ...;
tableView.setItems(new GuavaTableConverter(table));
```

but can't find anything like a `GuavaTableConverter` with a few web searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather easy to do this yourself. Just create a column for every value in `columnKeySet()` and a item for every value in `rowKeySet()`:

```
public final class GuavaTableConverter {

    private GuavaTableConverter() {
    }

    public static <R, C, V> List<TableColumn<R, String>> getColumns(Table<R, C, V> table, Function<C, String> headingConverter, Function<V, String> valueConverter) {
        Set<C> columns = table.columnKeySet();
        List<TableColumn<R, String>> result = new ArrayList<>(columns.size());
        for (C c : columns) {
            TableColumn<R, String> col = new TableColumn<>(headingConverter.apply(c));
            col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                V value = table.get(cd.getValue(), c);
                return value == null ? null : valueConverter.apply(value);
            }));
            result.add(col);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static <R> TableColumn<R, String> getRowColumn(Table<R, ? , ?> table, String name, Function<R, String> converter) {
        TableColumn<R, String> column = new TableColumn<>(name);
        column.setCellValueFactory(c -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> converter.apply(c.getValue())));
        return column;
    }

    public static <R> ObservableList<R> getItems(Table<R, ?, ?> table) {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(table.rowKeySet());
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    HashBasedTable<Integer, Integer, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();

    table.put(0, 0, "Hello World");
    table.put(2, 0, "A");
    table.put(2, 42, "B");

    TableView<Integer> tv = new TableView<>(GuavaTableConverter.getItems(table));
    tv.getColumns().add(GuavaTableConverter.getRowColumn(table, "row", Object::toString));
    tv.getColumns().addAll(GuavaTableConverter.getColumns(table, Object::toString, Object::toString));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tv));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```